# Wrong page numbers in pdf bookmarks in two-part document

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, links, bookmarks

I'm writing a two-part document, where the second part has roman page-numbering and its own table of contents. Unfortunately, some sections in the second part (starting with the section 'Second Part') have wrong (i.e. arabic) page numbers in the pdf bookmarks, but **not** in the document's table of content. Here is a picture of what I mean and a minimal working example:

[image: Screenshot of pdf bookmarks in the document]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\section{A section}  
Second one
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum
\section{Another section}
\lipsum

\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{1}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
\renewcommand\thesection{S\arabic{section}}

\newcommand{\newindex}{\Large Contents}
\newlistof{ind}{tce}{\newindex}
\newcommand\newsection[1]{%
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{tce}{section}{\protect\makebox[1.3em][l]{\thesection}#1}}
\newcommand\newsubsection[1]{%
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{tce}{subsection}{\protect\makebox[2.1em][l]{\thesubsection}#1}}

\begin{center}
\bf \Large 
Second Part:
\end{center}
\bigskip

\listofind

\section{Second Part}
\newsection{Second Part}
Some text

\section{Further Section}
\newsection{Further Section}
\lipsum

\subsection{Subsection I}
\newsubsection{Subsection I}

\subsection{Subsection II}
\newsubsection{Subsection II}

\section{Last section}
\newsection{Last section}

\subsection{Subsection III}
\newsubsection{Subsection III}
\lipsum

\subsection{Subsection IV}
\newsubsection{Subsection IV}

\end{document}
```

How can I ensure that the bookmarks of the second part have roman numbers? I had a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209035/bookmarks-to-the-second-part-leads-to-the-wrong-page-page-of-the-first-part), but made no progress.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: redefine also \theHsection: \renewcommand\theHsection{S\arabic{section}}

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This worked, thank you very much